# How to access an xml file from another method?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

i am trying to make an application that produces an xml file from user input, this is done through 2 forms, the main form has made the basics of the xml document and now i wish to populate the "members" from another xml that is being created in another form. However my issue is i dont want a button press to make a new xml file every time i click it to add a member so i have the basic part in form_load, however i cant access the xml file from a button press due to the error "The name 'xmlMembers' does not exist in the current context"
Code below:

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlNode member = xmlMembers.CreateElements("member"); //Causes error

        XmlAttribute attID = xmlMembers.CreateAttribute("id"); //Causes error
        attID.Value = MPlayID;
        member.Attributes.Append(attID);

        XmlAttribute attNick = XmlMembers.CreateAttribute("nick"); //Causes error
        attNick.Value = MNick;
        member.Attributes.Append(attNick);
    }

    private void Form_Member_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlMembers = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode rootNode = xmlMembers.CreateElement("members");
        xmlMembers.AppendChild(rootNode);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xmlMembers doesn't need to be declared in the form load :

```
        class YourClass
        {
             XmlDocument xmlMembers = null;

             private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
             {
                if (xmlMembers != null)
                {
                    XmlNode member = xmlMembers.CreateElements("member"); //Causes error

                    XmlAttribute attID = xmlMembers.CreateAttribute("id"); //Causes error
                    attID.Value = MPlayID;
                    member.Attributes.Append(attID);

                    XmlAttribute attNick = xmlMembers.CreateAttribute("nick"); //Causes error
                    attNick.Value = MNick;
                    member.Attributes.Append(attNick);
                }
             }

             private void Form_Member_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
             {
                    xmlMembers = new XmlDocument();
                    XmlNode rootNode = xmlMembers.CreateElement("members");
                    xmlMembers.AppendChild(rootNode);                    
             }
        }
```